# Show Custom Error handling message in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 and this config in Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

as I simply show the 404 NotFound in UI , I wanna to show the

```
Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request
```

message with my layout! not in a blank page 
where is it's configuration ??

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have to add it (controller, view).

You cannot configure something that doesn't exist.
If you fiddle the "blank page" I suspect you will see a 404 http code meaning that the request didn't find the not-found page.

Comment: I got the NotFound error in the case when there is no page , but in server errors I got that message in blank page , I wanna to handle it and show in my own view not in blank page

Comment: Ok, as I said you will have to add the controller "ErrorController" and a "NotFound.cshtml" view. Do you have them? You will then be able to add the custom message to your "NotFound.cshtml" view.

Comment: yes I have NotFound action and view and that is because it works , but ServerError action does not work

Comment: why do you expect ServerError to have something? server errors are in the 5xx http codes class. we are talking about 404.

Comment: or perhaps I didn't understand where the problem is

Comment: ahh, so you have 2 error views, NotFound and ServerError. NotFound works and ServerError does not? Is that it? if that's it then you need a new config line <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/ServerError" />

Comment: there is no any error , I works although I have not do anything for that! but if I could show it with my layout i it would better!